# Model selective usage of sum type

Tags: haskell

I'm not sure how to model correctly something. Consider a sum type

```
data Choice
    = A
    | B
    | C
```

and two types

```
data Foo = Foo
    { name : String
    , choice : Choice
    }

data Bar = Bar
    { name : String
    , choice : Choice
    }
```

As it is they are equal. I would like to impose that `Foo` could use only `A` and `B` as `Choice`, while `Bar` could use just `B` and `C`.

For the moment I solved this splitting `Choice` in two, like

```
data ChoiceFoo
    = FooA
    | FooB

data ChoiceBar
    = BarB
    | BarC
```

but it doesn't look a very scalable approach. Is there a better and/or more elegant solution?

Comment: As far as I know there is no solution. A type system specifies the *type* of the elements, it says nothing about the values. Usually you aim to define types such that invalid values are not possible (or at least most of them). You can also define code contracts, but there are *no* hard constraints, you can only hope that a contract prover *can* proof that the contracts are satisfied (but this is in general an undecidable problem).

Comment: I wish this was doable in general -- I was looking for something like this a long time ago. It would provide a sort of subtyping which Haskell lacks. I am aware of no general solution, though.

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach is to use a GADT as follows. It is not that general, though, since a constructor can be associated to either a single type (e.g. `ForFoo,ForBar`), or to any type (using `forAny` as a type variable).

```
data Purpose = ForFoo | ForBar

data Choice (p :: Purpose) where
    A :: Choice 'ForFoo
    B :: Choice forAny  -- can be any Purpose
    C :: Choice 'ForBar

data Foo where
    Foo :: { nameF :: String , choiceF :: Choice 'ForFoo } -> Foo

data Bar where
    Bar :: { nameB :: String , choiceB :: Choice 'ForBar } -> Bar
```

If we need to express that a choice is for `Foo,Bar` but not `Baz`, this approach can not be used.

---

A more general approach could be:

```
data Choice2 (a::Bool) (b::Bool) (c::Bool) where
    A2 :: Choice2 'True 'False 'False
    B2 :: Choice2 'False 'True 'False
    C2 :: Choice2 'False 'False 'True

data Foo2 where
    Foo2 :: { nameF2 :: String
            , choiceF2 :: Choice2 b1 b2 'False  } -> Foo2

data Bar2 where
    Bar2 :: { nameB2 :: String
            , choiceB2 :: Choice2 'False b1 b2 } -> Bar2

data Baz2 where
    Baz2 :: { nameZ2 :: String
            , choiceZ2 :: Choice2 b1 'False b2 } -> Baz2
```

This, in principle, allows one to express any "subset" requirement. We only need to require `False` in those cases we do not want, and use (existentially quantified) variables for the other cases.

It is still not completely general, and has its shortcomings. For instance, we should be able to write a constant-time implementation for

```
coerce :: [Choice2 'True b1 b2] -> [Choice2 'True 'False 'False]
```

but we can not, since we do not really have subtypes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modular sums

How about using the generic sum type `Either`:

```
data A = A
data B = B
data C = C

type (+) = Either

data Foo = Foo
  { name :: String
  , choice :: A + B
  }

data Bar = Bar
  { name :: String
  , choice = B + C
  }
```

Modularity is good, but it's not really convenient to have to remember to use the right combination of `Left` and `Right` when constructing and pattern-matching values. Furthermore, adding a case requires changing previously existing patterns.

However there are variants of this technique that address this problem.
Basically, use a typeclass to select/inject a variant in a sum. See for example [`Data.Vinyl.CoRec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.7.0/docs/Data-Vinyl-CoRec.html) in vinyl, where in particular, the [`match`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.7.0/docs/Data-Vinyl-CoRec.html#v:match) function makes it possible to pattern-match variants without worrying about order or nesting. In the comments I have a snippet that does something similar with prisms and the [total](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/total) library.

#### Flat parameterized sum

Another approach, which seems closer to your initial idea, is to declare a single sum type, but with type parameters that can forbid some constructors selectively.

chi already gave an example using GADTs. Here's one with regular ADTs.

```
data Choice a b c
  = A a
  | B b
  | C c
```

For there to be no `A` choice, just set `a ~ Void` (from `Data.Void`), which is an empty type.

```
data Foo = Foo
  { name :: String
  , choice :: Choice () () Void
    -- Two inhabitants: (A ()), (B ())
  }
```

We must still pattern-match on `C` to avoid warnings, but the case is systematically dispatched using `-XEmptyCase` or `Data.Void.absurd`.

```
case c :: Choice () () Void of
  A () -> 1
  B () -> 2
  C v -> case v of {}
  -- or  absurd v
```

This technique also allows some subtyping.

```
A () :: forall b c. Choice () b c
     :: Choice () () ()
     :: Choice () Void Void
     :: Choice () () Void
```

The downside is that to support a new (optional) choice means to change the number of type parameters, which is cumbersome.

Comment: A problem with this is that if there are five options (like `A + B + C + D + E`) we get those nice christmas trees like `Left (Left (Right C))`, and `Left (Left (Left (Left A))))`, etc.

Comment: Nothing magical prisms and the total library can't solve! http://lpaste.net/362494 (I'll add an explanation to my answer a bit later)